# Types of triangles admitting periodic billiard orbits

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, billiards

It is an open problem in dynamical systems if every triangle has a periodic billiard orbit.  So far it has been proven that equilateral triangles, isosceles triangles, right triangles, and obtuse triangles with no angle greater than 100 degrees have periodic billiard orbits.

I am wondering if there are any other broad or specific cases I am missing? For example, in [this](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/RM1992v047n03ABEH000893/pdf) paper, it is shown that any triangle with angles $\alpha$, $\beta$ satisfying $k\alpha=l\beta$ have a perpendicular periodic trajectory, where $k, l \in \mathbb{N}$ (page 13). There is a similar finding in [this paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0036144599355725) stating that every triangle with angles $\alpha$, $\beta$ satisfying $k\alpha + n\beta = \pi$, where  $k, n \in \mathbb{N}$ admits a perpendicular periodic trajectory.

Does anyone know of any other general cases?  I am particularly interested in the existence of cases where triangles have periodic trajectories when its angles are given by some function, that is if $\alpha$ is an angle in triangle $T$, then the second angle used to define $T$ is $\beta = f(\alpha)$ for example.  My department doesn't have people specializing in this area, so I apologize in advance if my question does not belong here or is unclear, give any comments and I will try my best to reciprocate.

Comment: Masur proved that billiards where all the angles are rational multiples of pi have periodic trajectories.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas thanks yes that is one I forgot to mention in my post, I don’t believe I am aware of any past those however

Comment: All acute triangles have periodic billiard paths.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche : this is contained in the OPs statement that if all angles are below 100 degrees...

Comment: You mean the one that says "*obtuse* triangles with no angle greater than 100 degrees"?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas (sorry, I forgot to ping you.)

Comment: Sorry- I guess formally the acute statement is not included, although a restated theorem including both cases would be triangles, all of whose angles are less than 100 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

This paper in 2018 showed that all obtuse triangles with angles at most 112.3 degrees have periodic trajectories. It's also a computed assisted proof but not the same method as Richard Schwarz's. https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.06667